# A problem about the quotient space of an extended Dirichlet space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, dirichlet-forms

Let $(\mathscr{E},\mathscr{F})$ be a recurrent Dirichlet form on $L^2(X;m)$ and $\mathscr{F}_e$ the corresponding extended Dirichlet space, then $1\in\mathscr{F}_e$ and $\mathscr{E}(1,1)=0$. Let ${\dot{\mathscr{F}_e}}$ be the quotient space of $\mathscr{F}_e$ with respect to the constant functions.

Let $\{u_n\}\subseteq{\mathscr{F}}$ and $\{c_n\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ satisfy
$$\mathscr{E}(u_n-u_m,u_n-u_m)\to0, \text{as } m,n\to+\infty,$$
$$u_n+c_n\to u,m\text{-a.e.}.$$

Is it true that $\dot{u}\in\dot{\mathscr{F}_e}$?

I think it is correct but can not give a proof. Could someone give some help?

Answer (score 1):

Because $1\in\mathscr F_e$ and $\mathscr E(1,1)=0$, each $u_n+c_n$ is an element of $\mathscr F_e$, and $(u_n+c_n)$ is $\mathscr E$-Cauchy. Because $u_n+c_n\to u$, $m$-a.e., the limit $u$ is an element of $(\mathscr F_e)_e$. The latter coincides with $\mathscr F_e$ (confirming your suspicion) under the condition that each element of $\mathscr F$ be of $\sigma$-finite support (in particular, if $m$ is $\sigma$-finite). See Lemma 3 on page 2 of http://www.stat.ualberta.ca/people/schmu/preprints/extend.pdf